# Save data from Watson Assistant to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: websphere, google-sheets-api, watson-assistant

I would like to save some info from watson assistant to my google spreadsheet and was not sure what to use to do this,

- IBM Cloud function Action
- IBM App Connect

Any guidance or code sample would be much appreciated

Comment: You can also use another compute option, it only needs to be a webhook

Comment: What kind of data do you need to save in Google spreadsheet? Some variables gathered while chatting with the assistant or data about the Watson Assistant skill ?(intents/nodes/entities/things not necessarily retrieved in a response got from the dialog skill while chatting)

Comment: @adcsie who can variables be stored in google spreadsheet?